MSRC Security Updates API Filter By Product
The sample code shows how to filter by CVE and hints that you can filter by product. But there is only one product tree. How do you filter by product?
$CVEsWanted = @(
        "CVE-2017-0001", 
        "CVE-2017-0005"
        )
$CVRFHtmlProperties = @{
    Vulnerability = $CVRFDoc.Vulnerability | Where-Object {$_.CVE -in $CVEsWanted}
    ProductTree = $CVRFDoc.ProductTree
}
Get-MsrcVulnerabilityReportHtml @CVRFHtmlProperties -Verbose | Out-File $Output_Location

I tried something like this, but this just filters within the Product tree.
$Products = @(
        "Windows 10 Version 1809 for x64-based Systems", 
        "Windows Server 2016",
        "Windows Server 2016 (Server Core installation)"
        )

$ProductsOfInterest = $CVRFDoc.ProductTree.FullProductName | Where-Object {$_.Value -in $Products}

I think I have to make a whole new ProductTree object with just the items I want in it, but that seems overly complicated for the API.
